# How to clear a cached query?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, pydal

I'm using the following method to cache the result of a SQL query:

```
db(my_query).select(cache=(cache.ram, 3600), cacheable=True)
```

In some cases I want to clear this cache before it expires, which could be done by using `cache.ram.clear(key)` but I actually don't know the key generated by the DAL in the previous code.

I understand `cache=(cache.ram, 0)` will clear the cache too, but I also have the overhead of executing the query.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache key is a bit complicated to replicate (it is the MD5 hash of the database URI plus the SQL generated for the query). As an alternative, since you have `cacheable=True`, you can call `cache.ram` directly with your own key:

```
rows = cache.ram('my_query', lambda: db(my_query).select(cacheable=True), 3600)
```